# Twitter Bootstrap Lightbox display YouTube Video

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I'm working on my site and am still very new to HTML. I'm trying to show YouTube videos in a lightbox using Twitter Bootstrap and the Twitter Bootstrap Lightbox code I found here: http://jbutz.github.io/bootstrap-lightbox/

I've been able to get images to load in the lightbox. But, I'm not sure what I need to do to get the YouTube video to play instead. When I look at the YouTube documentation it provides both iframe and embed options. But, when I replace the  code with one of these and change the link to my videos the lightbox doesn't load and of course the video can't be seen.

Here is my code using the embed option:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      <h4>Band Concert</h4>
        <div id="bandlightbox1" class="lightbox hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="lightbox-content">
            <embed
                width="420" height="345"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og8cxXICoVU"
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
            </embed>
              <div class="lightbox-caption">
                <p>This is a video of my friends and I at our band concert. The guy in that glasses is our teacher person. The song is Friday I'm in Love for anyone who doesn't know. I'm on the piano that sounds like a harpsichord.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I'm still really new and I'm stumped.

Thanks

Comment: That lightbox is just for images.  Plus you can look in their github and see that there's only one content type, which is images. There are many light boxes that handle media of various types. One is: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/, really great!

Answer (score 2):

```
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../dist/ekko-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Example #4: Gallery of YouTube Videos

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                        <div class="row">
                            <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6mFF3VmVAs" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="youtubevideos" class="col-sm-4">
                                <img src="//i1.ytimg.com/vi/yP11r5n5RNg/mqdefault.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                            </a>
                            <a href="http://youtu.be/iQ4D273C7Ac" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="youtubevideos" class="col-sm-4">
                                <img src="//i1.ytimg.com/vi/iQ4D273C7Ac/mqdefault.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                            </a>
                            <a href="//www.youtube.com/embed/b0jqPvpn3sY" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="youtubevideos" class="col-sm-4">
                                <img src="//i1.ytimg.com/vi/b0jqPvpn3sY/mqdefault.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function ($) {
                // delegate calls to data-toggle="lightbox"
                $(document).delegate('*[data-toggle="lightbox"]', 'click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return $(this).ekkoLightbox({
                        onShown: function() {
                            if (window.console) {
                                return console.log('Checking our the events huh?');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
});
```

first you have to add ekko-lightbox CSS and js file.
and jquery code for data-toggle="lightbox" .

You can see here: http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#single-image
in href give url of youtube video and set  data-toggle,data-gallery property

Comment: So pleased with finding this answer. It's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!